# NSMutableArray insertObject atIndex

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have `NSMutableArray *myArray = nil;`. If I will use `[myArray insertObject:@"Hello" atIndex:0]` method to this array, will it be allocated automatically?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It will just send the message to nil.

It would be equivalent to;

```
[nil insertObject:@"Hello" atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Objective-C lets you message nil, so `[myArray insertObject:@"Hello" atIndex:0]` becomes `[nil insertObject:@"Hello" atIndex:0]` and will take the fast path in the runtime to doing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

NSMutableArray *nil = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[nil insertObject:@"How" atIndex:0];